# Remove controls in Android

Tags: html, video

How can I remove the controls in Android? Currently, controls="false" this removes the play button in iPhones. How about in Android?

```
<video playsinline loop muted autoplay controls="false" class="fillWidth" poster="assets/images/Snapshots/The-Launch.jpg">
  <source src="assets/images/MP4/The-Launch.mp4" type="video/mp4" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
  <source src="assets/images/MP4/The-Launch.webm" type="video/webm" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
</video>
```

Comment: have you tried just removing the `controls` reference altogether? It's a binary switch - so if you have `<video.... controls>` they'll show but, like `muted`, if you don't have it then they shouldn't